# ie8 and 7 Permission Denied when trying to load an external js file

Tags: javascript, html, permission-denied

Using http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js to enable html5 in older ie browsers (client wants html5).

But when the page loads I'm getting a "Permission Denied" error, then a whole other bunch of errors occur that I think are related to the html5.js file not working.

I don't know much about javascript so any thoughts on this would be super helpful.

Here's the link to my page: http://supermarchepa.com/v3/eng/index.html

Thanks in advance

EDIT: ok, fixed the flowplayer issue, also now linking to html5.js locally and still having the same issue. [image]

jquery file is now linked locally too.

UPDATE FIXED: Issue was the following code:

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});

Wrapped it in  so that ie ignores it and it's all good now.

Thanks everyone who helped me through this.

Comment: Could you please specify the debug output?

Comment: Are you calling html5.js from a different domain?  That could lead to this error.

Comment: hmmm... `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://supermarchepa.com/v3/js/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"` - I think you should fix this first

Comment: Save the file to local and load it from there, instead of google so at least no cross-domain issues guaranteed. No IE here but you have a 404 for flowplayer as well.

Comment: Now loading html5.js and jquery-1.7.2.min.js locally, still no luck.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer instead of an edit on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

Issue was the following code:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() { 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        window.scrollTo(0, 1); 
    }, 0); 
});
```

I wrapped it in conditional comment tags (`<!--[if !IE]><!-->`) so that Internet Explorer ignores it and it's all good now.

Moral of the story, if you're having trouble with a script, anything on the page can be the problem and not just the script that's giving you error messages.

Thanks everyone who helped me through this.